# Change the behavior of html subscription form submit button

Tags: html, forms

I am using an html theme and on the page where I want to collect the emails is a newsletter subscription form. I want to change the behaviour of the submit button which user clicks after filling the email id. I want it to direct the user to a landing page. Right now, it just opens a pop-up message of confirmation. Subscription form is a mailchimp form, but the data goes into a text file on my web hosting.

Below is the code-

```
<div class="newsletter1">
                        <form action="form-data/notify-me.php" class="form-widget" data-formtype="newsletter">
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <input class="form-control" data-label="Email" required data-msg="Please enter email." type="email" name="email" placeholder="Subscribe for pre-launch offers">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript.

```
var doc = document;
var div = doc.getElementsByTagName('button');

button[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
  window.location = '/landing-page';
});
```

- or (based on comment) -

change button element to anchor element with href="/langing-page" with type="submit"

Comment: This is a separate code for the form? I was thinking if I can edit the existing code and convert the submit button action to a landing page.